# Push multidimensional object to an array and get an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am calling an API and got a response an an object in the following form. I would like to append the objects to an array in order to iterate them later.

Using push I got a list of strings == `['Account','AccountName','AccountServiceHomepage']`
I would like to push the entire object to the array so for x[0] I get Account as an object not as a string.

Does anyone have a clue?

**Snippet**

```js
let properties = {
  Account: {
    label: 'Account',
    key: 'Account',
    description: { en: '' },
    prefLabel: { en: 'test' },
    usageCount: '0'
  },
  AccountName: {
    label: 'AccountName',
    key: 'AccountName',
    description: { en: '' },
    prefLabel: { en: '' },
    usageCount: '0'
  },
  AccountServiceHomepage: {
    label: 'AccountServiceHomepage',
    key: 'AccountServiceHomepage',
    description: { en: '' },
    prefLabel: { en: '' },
    usageCount: '0'
  }
}  
  
x = [];
for (i in properties) {
  x.push(i);
};

console.log(x);
```

Comment: PS:: properties is the name of object

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `x.push(properties[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

```js
let x = Object.values(properties)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let properties = {
  Account: {
    label: 'Account',
    key: 'Account',
    description: { en: '' },
    prefLabel: { en: 'test' },
    usageCount: '0'
  },
  AccountName: {
    label: 'AccountName',
    key: 'AccountName',
    description: { en: '' },
    prefLabel: { en: '' },
    usageCount: '0'
  },
  AccountServiceHomepage: {
    label: 'AccountServiceHomepage',
    key: 'AccountServiceHomepage',
    description: { en: '' },
    prefLabel: { en: '' },
    usageCount: '0'
  }
}

x = [];
for (i in properties) {
  x.push(properties[i]);
};

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Up vote, but answers should also include a description of how the code works.  For example, "Change the code to push the object rather than the key name using x.push(properties[i])"

Answer (score 0):

You can convert object to an array (ignoring keys) like this:

```js
const items = Object.values();
```

Comment: `values` returns already an array, not an iterator.

Comment: @NinaScholz right, I keep forgetting which ones return an array. What were the examples returning an iterator?

Comment: for example [`Array#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys).

Comment: @NinaScholz oh yeah, so `[1, 2, 3].keys()` returns an array, but `Object.keys([1, 2, 3])` returns an iterator. What a mess, I wonder if the only explanation of this is legacy.

Comment: vice versa ....

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for (let property in properties) {
    propertiesArray.push(properties[property]);
}
```

Comment: rather iterate the `Object.keys()` to avoid unexpected inherited properties. (might as well use `Object.values()` at that point)